# Returning objects with lapply

Tags: r, list, return, lapply

a small question. I'm trying to get the values for the network indicies (fl_wp_mod, fl_wp_den) stored in seperate variables after running the function. I tried this but I'm able to get it.
Any idea why?
Sorry, I'm new to lapply and R in general.

```
cluster_modularity = function(graph_object){
fl_wp_ig <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(graph_object) 
fl_wp_cw <- cluster_walktrap(fl_wp_ig) 
fl_wp_mod <- modularity(fl_wp_cw) 
fl_den <- edge_density(fl_wp_ig, loops = FALSE) 
return(c(fl_wp_mod, fl_den)) 
} 
Mod = lapply(fl_wp_n, cluster_modularity[1]) #fl_wp_n is the raw data
Den = lapply(fl_wp_n, cluster_modularity[2]) #Both these lines are giving me errors
```

Comment: Thanks. Now you are more than welcome to vote up my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sapply` is more convenient here.

```
ans <- sapply(fl_wp_n, cluster_modularity)
Mod <- ans[1, ]
Den <- ans[2, ]
```